# iptables silently dropping packets with docker DNAT at end of PREROUTING chain instead of continuing to INPUT chain

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, port, docker-network

I have a docker compose file with 2 services that I want to both listen to port 80, but on different IP addresses (reverse proxy is not suitable for these). I have a virtual network interface with a separate IP for the second service to listen to.
When I list a specific IP address for a service to bind to, it isn't accessible from the network anymore. But it is when no IP is specified and only 1 service is bound to port 80.

Example:
When my docker-compose file contains:

```
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.2:80:80"
```

I can successfully connect from my local machine using `curl 192.168.1.2`, but not from a machine on the local network.

However, when my docker-compose file contains:

```
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

I can successfully connect from the network using `curl 192.168.1.2`. Which is the same IP I was binding to before! So this is clearly the IP address of one of my network interfaces.

It doesn't seem to be firewall related, because if I run `sudo python3 -m http.server 80 --bind 192.168.1.2` I can also reach it from the network. So why does docker not respond from outside requests when configured with a specific IP address?

Edit:
Yes, I use Linux. Output from `iptables -t nat -S` with IP specified for port 80:

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N OUTPUT_direct
-N POSTROUTING_ZONES
-N POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-N POSTROUTING_direct
-N POST_public
-N POST_public_allow
-N POST_public_deny
-N POST_public_log
-N PREROUTING_ZONES
-N PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-N PREROUTING_direct
-N PRE_public
-N PRE_public_allow
-N PRE_public_deny
-N PRE_public_log
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.240.0/20 ! -o br-d7a59c2d8d7f -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-a6d78077661d -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.240.4/32 -d 192.168.240.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.240.4/32 -d 192.168.240.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7890 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.240.4/32 -d 192.168.240.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.240.4/32 -d 192.168.240.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i br-d7a59c2d8d7f -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-a6d78077661d -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d7a59c2d8d7f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.240.4:8080
-A DOCKER ! -i br-a6d78077661d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:53
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d7a59c2d8d7f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7890 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.240.4:7890
-A DOCKER ! -i br-a6d78077661d -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:53
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d7a59c2d8d7f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.240.4:443
-A DOCKER -d 192.168.1.2/32 ! -i br-d7a59c2d8d7f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.240.4:80
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eth0 -g POST_public
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth0 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
```

After adding TRACE rules I've found that the external packets follow the PREROUTING chain all the way to the relevant DNAT rule. Log excerpt:

```
TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:rule:4 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=52:54:00:83:f9:b4:50:ed:3c:23:4d:b9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.250 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49864 DPT=80 SEQ=400376858 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303060101080A7F6085070000000004020000)

TRACE: nat:DOCKER:rule:9 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=52:54:00:83:f9:b4:50:ed:3c:23:4d:b9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.250 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49864 DPT=80 SEQ=400376858 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B4010303060101080A7F6085070000000004020000)
```

But then the trail ends. It doesn't continue with neither the INPUT or FILTER chain. Since the ip I was using is the ip of a virtual interface, I tried disabling strict RPF after reading https://serverfault.com/questions/586628/packets-sent-on-virtual-ip-dont-hit-iptables-rule?newreg=edb07f9ec9ee416f8bd012ee6d94b8b9, through `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2`. This didn't help however. I also tried replacing `192.168.1.2` with `192.168.1.238`, which is the ip of the physical NIC, with similar results. The `nstat -rsz | grep IPReversePathFilter` counter is not increasing between requests either. I don't get why the packets are just silently dropped.

---

I've realised that my web server itself doesn't actually need to have ads blocked by pihole, so I have decided to use a macvlan network for this docker container instead. This also gives it a separate ip address, but with the caveat that it and the rest of the host cannot communicate with each other.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Debian with an additional IP added to an interface. Add results of `iptables -t nat -S` (when it doesn't wok) to the question if you are using Linux.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping out! I've edited the post with the output.